# Fail to read embedded resources

Tags: java, embedded-resource

I want to embed a txt file into runnable jar and read it. I tried using this code

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/src/kan/master_ship.txt"),"UTF-8");
```

But it gives

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at kan.util.Master.loadMasterShip(Master.java:37)
    at kan.util.Master.load(Master.java:26)
    at kan.Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

And it was in the eclipse debug environment. Any help?

---

After that I tried to export it as runnable jar, and it works. But I cannot switch the code for debug and export each time. It should be in this way!

Comment: getClass().getResourceAsStream("/src/kan/master_ship.txt") could be returning null

Comment: @sanket the issue is, why

Comment: Try getClass().getResourceAsStream("master_ship.txt") this way

Comment: I find the rules governing how `getResourceAsStream` to be quite confusing.  Try instead starting with `getResource` for an `URL`.

Comment: @Octopus That does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getClass().getResourceAsStream` will find a resource base on the classpath.

So you must sure that the file you want to open is in the class path. As I see you are trying to find the file in the `src/kan/master_ship.txt` which is not in the class path. try `/kan/master_ship.txt` and make sure you have the `kan` folder and a `master_ship.txt` file in it and the folder is in the class path.

In the eclipse the class path is usually named target.

Answer (score 2):

You are not able to provide correct path. It could be well when you test it from source ide but it would be fail when you referenced it for runnable jar.

try to put it in constructor and reference it. it work for me once.

```
public myClass(){
BufferedInputStream file= (BufferedInputStream) this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/a.txt");
        try {
            System.out.println((char)file.read());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```